# Select every date where date is equal to today's date minus 1 day - Not working with dateadd on Month/year - T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Like the title says, I am trying to build a query that selects all records from a database table where the date is equal to yesterdays date.

The date column in the table is however of the format `datetime` (with hours, minutes, seconds as well) so I do the select based on the dates year, month and day (times don't matter as long as the date is yesterday).

To achieve this I have build the following query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    qryTouchBoekingen 
WHERE 
    (DATEPART(yyyy, myDateTime) = DATEADD(dd, -1, Datepart(dd, GetDate())) 
    AND (DATEPART(mm, myDateTime) = DATEADD(dd, -1, Datepart(mm, GetDate())) 
    AND (DATEPART(dd, myDateTime) = DATEADD(dd, -1, Datepart(dd, GetDate())) )
ORDER BY
    Starttijd ASC
```

Though this doesn't return any records. When I only use it on the day part of the `myDateTime` column then it works (but obviously also returns all other years and months with that specific date).

I also couldn't do it using:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    qryTouchBoekingen 
WHERE 
    myDateTime = DATEADD(dd, -1, GetDate())
```

because this give errors on the `time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this much simpler version:

```
cast(myDateTime as date) = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)
```

Or, even better:

```
(myDateTime >=  cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date) and
 myDateTime < cast(getdate() as date)
)
```

This version is more explicit in its ability to take advantage of an index.  (The first will also take advantage of an index on `myDateTime`, but that is an exception to the rule that functions preclude the use of indexes.)

Comment: Ah superb! Indeed much better this way! Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify- leaving the column being filtered by untouched allows it to make use of the index, but are you saying that the are special optimizations for casting of datetime to date? (assuming as it must be used a lot)

Comment: @gordatron . . . Yes.  When `date` was introduced in SQL Server 2008, casting a `datetime` to a `date` was also made sargable.  Here is a rather detailed discussion of how it works:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.
You should count previous day before making datepart from it

```
Select * from qryTouchBoekingen 
WHERE ( DATEPART(yyyy, myDateTime) = Datepart(dd, DATEADD(dd, -1, GetDate())) 
AND (DATEPART(mm, myDateTime) = Datepart(mm, DATEADD(dd, -1, GetDate())) 
AND (DATEPART(dd, myDateTime) = Datepart(dd, DATEADD(dd, -1, GetDate())) )
Order by Starttijd ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up and answer!

Answer (score 0):

DOes this work:

```
Select 
    * 
from 
    qryTouchBoekingen 
WHERE 
    CAST( myDateTime AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GetDate()) AS DATE)
Order by 
    Starttijd ASC
```